# Lodash filter and remove like java streams

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, stream, lodash

I have a tree data structure in a nodejs app that use lodash:

```js
var l = require("lodash");

obj_string = 
`
[
    {
      "father_id": 1,
      "name": "father 1",
      "child_array": [
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "father 1 child 1"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "father 1 child 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "father_id": 2,
      "name": "father 2",
      "child_array": [
        {
          "child_id": 21,
          "name": "father 2 child 1"
        },
        {
          "child_id": 22,
          "name": "father 2 child 2 - TO DELETE"
        }
      ]
    }  
  ]
`;
tree = JSON.parse(obj_string);
```

I want to remove a child by id and i don't know what is his father:

```
l.chain(tree).flatMap(f=>f.child_array).remove(c=>c.child_id==22);
```

It does not work, why!? I used java streams and I don't understand how really works lodash.
For example, if I want to search a child and i want a reference to the founded child, for example in order to edit it's members (without _.map), how can I do?

With this:

```
ret = l.chain(tree).flatMap(f=>f.child_array).find(c=>c.child_id==22).value();
```

I have a new object in ret, so i can't access/edit the original one.
In other word, the second question is: how i can retreive an object reference from a lodash wrapper?

Comment: May be you could try with https://highlandjs.org/ it allows you to work with streams and backpresure

Comment: i take a look, thank you

Comment: @Salvo are you parsing from a string? and then you have to update the parsed (original) object (removing child with id <some-id>)? then there is a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the array and reject the items in `child_array`, which you don't need. Note that this will modify the original object.

```js
const obj = [{"father_id":1,"name":"father 1","child_array":[{"id":11,"name":"father 1 child 1"},{"id":12,"name":"father 1 child 2"}]},{"father_id":2,"name":"father 2","child_array":[{"child_id":21,"name":"father 2 child 1"},{"child_id":22,"name":"father 2 child 2 - TO DELETE"}]}];

_.forEach(obj, item => {
  item.child_array = _.reject(item.child_array, {child_id: 22});
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is not easy applicable, in the original data structure i have a very big and deep tree structure, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can also use Vanilla `ES6` to achieve similar output like this:

```js
var arr =[{"father_id":1,"name":"father 1","child_array":[{"id":11,"name":"father 1 child 1"},{"id":12,"name":"father 1 child 2"}]},{"father_id":2,"name":"father 2","child_array":[{"child_id":21,"name":"father 2 child 1"},{"child_id":22,"name":"father 2 child 2 - TO DELETE"}]}];

var newArr = arr.map(obj => {
  return obj.child_array[0].child_id ? 
         (obj.child_array = obj.child_array.filter(c => c.child_id != 22), obj) 
         : obj;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to realize that `lodash` works exactly as expected in your example. The issue is you did `flatMap(f=>f.child_array)` which told lodash to take the `child_array` and return it to the next chain operation. Next it did as expected remove the child which matched on the id and what is now left is the child collection you requested via the return from `flatMap`.

It seems what you really want is map through the `fathers` remove the child which matches on the id and then return `the father`.

For example this would do that:

```js
var data = [{"father_id":1,"name":"father 1","child_array":[{"id":11,"name":"father 1 child 1"},{"id":12,"name":"father 1 child 2"}]},{"father_id":2,"name":"father 2","child_array":[{"child_id":21,"name":"father 2 child 1"},{"child_id":22,"name":"father 2 child 2 - TO DELETE"}]}];

removeById = (id, data) => _.map(data, father => {
  father.child_array = _.reject(father.child_array, { child_id: id })
  return father
})

console.log(removeById(22, data)) // 2 fathers with 2nd child removed from 2nd father
console.log(removeById(11, data)) // 2 fathers with 1 child each now
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). We use object-scan for a lot of our data processing.

Note that this solution will modify the original object.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const prune = (id, input) => objectScan(['**'], {
  abort: true, // abort after first match
  rtn: 'bool',
  filterFn: ({ value, parent, property }) => {
    if (value.child_id === id) {
      parent.splice(property, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(input);

const obj = [ { father_id: 1, name: 'father 1', child_array: [ { id: 11, name: 'father 1 child 1' }, { id: 12, name: 'father 1 child 2' } ] }, { father_id: 2, name: 'father 2', child_array: [ { child_id: 21, name: 'father 2 child 1' }, { child_id: 22, name: 'father 2 child 2 - TO DELETE' } ] } ];

console.log(prune(22, obj)); // returns true iff replacement made
// => true
console.log(obj);
// => [ { father_id: 1, name: 'father 1', child_array: [ { id: 11, name: 'father 1 child 1' }, { id: 12, name: 'father 1 child 2' } ] }, { father_id: 2, name: 'father 2', child_array: [ { child_id: 21, name: 'father 2 child 1' } ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)